# Group rings such that every (countably generated) module has a maximal submodule

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, group-algebras, group-rings

Every (non-zero) finitely generated module over a ring has a maximal proper submodule by a simple application of Zorn's lemma.

I am interested in the following question, with two variants.

> > Variant 1: For which groups $G$ does every (non-zero) $\mathbb CG$-module have a maximal proper submodule.
> >
> > Variant 2: For which groups $G$ does every countably generated (non-zero) $\mathbb CG$-module have a maximal proper submodule.

What I know about this:

1. If $G$ is finite, then the answer to Variant 1 (and hence 2) is yes since every (non-zero) module $M$ over an Artinian ring $R$ has a maximal proper submodule (if $J$ is the radical of $R$, then $JM$ is proper because $J$ is nilpotent and so $M/JM$ is semisimple and hence has a simple quotient, whose kernel pulls back to a maximal submodule of $M$)?
2. If $G$ is commutative, then by the first theorem of [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43737225?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) Variant 1 holds for $\mathbb CG$ iff $G$ is locally finite (using complex group rings are semiprimitive and are von Neumann regular iff the group is locally finite)?

Comment: Just a remark (which you probably observed but for everybody): for every $G$ there exists a nonzero $\mathbf{Z}G$-module with no maximal proper submodule: say $\mathbf{Q}$ with the trivial action. Whence the restriction to $\mathbf{C}G$-modules.

Comment: If a module fails to have a maximal submodule then every generating set has the property that removing any finite subset from the generating set still yields a generating set.

Comment: The latter amounts to saying that a module with no maximal proper submodule has no nonzero finitely generated quotient. (In more general structures, e.g., groups, it rather says that an object with no maximal proper subobject is infinitely generated over every proper subobject.)

Comment: Yes since finitely generated quotients have simple quotients.

Comment: Since for noetherian commutative rings, finitely cogenerated modules are the same as artinian modules (and are countably generated) — all this is in Lam's book—, every nonzero module admits a nonzero countably generated quotient. In particular, the existence of a nonzero module with no maximal proper submodule already implies that of a countably generated one.

Comment: That will take care of the commutative case. I better look at Lam

Comment: Not exactly, because you don't have noetherianity. Every non-torsion abelian group has a nonzero quotient that is torsion-free and locally cyclic (i.e., isomorphic to a nonzero subgroup of $Q$). It would be enough to deal with these groups.

Comment: Yes I was thinking finitely generated.

Comment: How do we get that the finitely co-generated are countably generated?  I never thought about it before.

Comment: It's a general easy fact, that artinian modules over arbitrary associative rings are countably generated. On the other hand, I only claimed the fact "finitely cogenerated" implies artinian (and hence countably generated), for modules over commutative noetherian rings.

Comment: @YCor thanks. I never much thought about Artinian modules of non finite length.

Comment: There are several natural conditions on general groups that specialize to “torsion” when the group is abelian. E.g., locally finite, or torsion, or generated by elements of finite order. Can you rule out any of these as the answer to Variant 1?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer about Variant 2: there are countably generated $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z]$-modules with no proper quotient.

First note that $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z]\cong \mathbb C[x,x^{-1}]$ is a PID.  The simple modules are just the quotients by maximal ideals, that is by ideals generated by irreducible elements, and any such quotient is a torsion module.

In the answer to [Injective indecomposable modules over Laurent polynomial rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313655/injective-indecomposable-modules-over-laurent-polynomial-rings), it is shown that there are injective=divisible $\mathbb C[x,x^{-1}]$-modules that have countable dimension over $\mathbb C$.  These are obviously countably generated.  They do not have simple quotients because any quotient of a divisible module is divisible and any torsion divisible module is trivial.  Hence they do not have maximal submodules.

I suspect that a similar argument shows that $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z^n]\cong \mathbb C[x_1^{\pm 1},\cdots,x_n^{\pm 1}]$ also has countably generated divisible modules.

Comment: Over a PID $A$ it's straightforward that the indecomposable modules the field of fractions and quotient of localizations $A[t^{-1}]/A$, $t$ irreducible: except the fraction field, the other ones are countably generated since $A[t^{-1}]$ is generated by $\{t^{-n}:n\ge 0\}$ as $A$-module. So indecomposable $\mathbf{C}[x,x^{-1}]$-modules are $\mathbf{C}(t)$ and $\mathbf{C}[t,t^{-1},(t-a)^{-1}]/\mathbf{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ for $a\in\mathbf{C}$. Except the first one. This is very standard (but I didn't catch the idea to use this PID group ring to solve your question).

Comment: Divisible torsion $C[Z^2]$-modules are much more tricky to consider. It's unclear to me whether you can embed any simple module into a countably generated one. I think that I read/heard that their injective envelope is known to be uncountably generated.

Comment: We just need at least one divisible is a countably generated module and that any simple is not divisible. @YCor

Comment: @YCor, maybe sounding like https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/jlms/s2-8.2.290 works for the trivial module.

Comment: I only realized this morning the connection of my question to divisible modules @YCor

Comment: Yes the reference should work for the trivial module (modulo a "change of coordinates"). What do they get? something countable-dimensional? (I don't have access)

Comment: They get a basis of polynomials with negative exponents so a countable basis.

Comment: OK, fine. By the way, Matlis duality yields a way to produce uncountably many modules over $Z^n$, $n\ge 2$, in which each of the $n$ commuting invertible operators acts a unipotent element, and in which the set of proper submodules is reduced to an increasing sequence (in particular they are uniserial and have no maximal submodules). Actually every non-artinian commutative noetherian ring admits such a module.

Comment: Are these countably generated?

Comment: Obviously, since they have only countably many submodules.

Comment: OK it is a sequence not a chain. I misread.